# adding the radio button for html page

Tags: html

In my html page, I cant add two radio buttons, I get an error in free-code-camp and that is about to have two radio buttons in label element with attribute of same name value for both of them in input self-closing tag.

I tried the same value for name attribute in input tag within the label element. but I got error.

```html
       <label>
<input id="indoor" type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor"   > Indoor
          </label> 
            <label> 
<input id="outdoor" type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor" > Outdoor
            </label>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows three radio buttons with the same name, within a label, within a form.

This is a valid structure.

```js
const handleSubmission = (form, event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(`Choice: ${form.elements.foo.value}`);
};
```

```html
<form onSubmit="handleSubmission(this, event)">
  <label>
    <strong>Choice:</strong>
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="a" /> A
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="b" /> B
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="c" /> C
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```